# scrolling down box with most recent feeds

Tags: jquery

I've taken a look at these three websites:

[www.foursquare.com](http://www.foursquare.com)
[www.untappd.com](http://www.untappd.com)
[www.getglue.com](http://www.getglue.com)

as you can see the main page has a scrolling down most recent activity box.
How do I create something like this?

Is this jquery or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its done with javascript, you can use jquery to make it easier on yourself. Heres a quick example

http://jsfiddle.net/tpmQj/

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
                  $("#wrapper").prepend($("<li>A new item</li>").hide().fadeIn());
    }, 4000); 
});
```

You could use a timeout, or an interval, coupled with an ajax request, that polls a database and returns new results etc. The basic concept is just appending the new items to the dom tree.

Comment: that is pretty cool, so you have to design everything, i.e: the box, etc... does the text comes from a database?

Comment: The content could come from anywhere, a database, or another web page like a live feed from twitter for example.

Comment: Actually there is, check the one out here, http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/ and a whole page of them here http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/10-awesome-jquery-tutorials-about-twitter/

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Loktar's version, this is more similar to 4square: http://www.jsfiddle.net/8ND53/

```
var newitem = function(){
    var item = $('<div>')
        .addClass('item')
        .css('display','none')
        .text('This is a brand new item')
        .prependTo('#scroller')
        .slideDown();
    $('#scroller .item:last').animate({height:'0px'},function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

setInterval(newitem, 2000);
```

Comment: Oh nice looks just like the 4square one.